# Script doesn't work unless executed in footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a weird situation. Despite making sure that all of its dependencies are loaded before it (in my case it's only jQuery library), my script doesn't work when loaded in the head section (i.e. `<head>`), but does its job when loaded in the footer (somewhere above `</body>` tag).

Since that's not clear enough, let me give a live example. [This is the web page](http://whatthenerd.com/2012/06/hello-world/). Now, view the source of the page, and in there, this is the code I am talking about.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var yjlSettings = {"gifUrl":"http:\/\/whatthenerd.com\/wp-content\/themes\/reddlec\/images\/ajax-loader.gif","autoGrow":"enable"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://whatthenerd.com/wp-content/themes/reddlec/js/no-reload-comments.js?ver=3.3.2'></script>
```

What it's supposed to do is allow users to post comments without reloading the page. (Please feel free to test comment on the page `:)` ) -- but it's doesn't. Why?

PS: Like I said earlier, everything works when the aforementioned scripts are loaded just before the `</body>` tag. I don't really see what could be causing the conflict.

Comment: The script probably needs elements that aren't loaded yet. (I.e. anything inside `<body>`.) -- Too late!

Comment: @Rudie `Too late!` yeah, but no problem at all. I've learnt something really important today! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script goes immediately out to find elements in the DOM:

```
var $commentlist = jQuery('.commentlist');
var $respond = jQuery('#respond');
```

Two examples found within the script. These items don't exist at the time the header is being loaded, but they do exist by the time the end of your body is reached. If you want to load this from your header, you need to wrap this in a document ready block:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.
});
```

This makes it safe to load at the top of your page by delaying the execution of your code until the document has fully loaded, and the DOM is constructed.

More about `ready` online at: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: do you think something like this would be better? `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ /* My Code Here */ });`

Comment: Go yell at the person who made that script :-P

Comment: @AahanKrish Sure, especially if you're using .noConflict.

Comment: @Rocket lol! It's a WordPress plugin, and it actually does load the file in footer. But a plugin is a waste when i only need some JS code from it. From that crop all these issues... :D

Comment: @JonathanSampson One last Q: Should I wrap the whole code in [this file](http://whatthenerd.com/wp-content/themes/reddlec/js/no-reload-comments.js) with `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...` or just the second block of code that starts with `var $commentlist=jQuery('.commentlist')....` ??

Comment: @AahanKrish Only code that relies on the DOM needs to be placed within the document ready callback. You don't need to declare functions, etc., within the document ready callback.

Comment: Just came back to say that it's working great now. Thanks a lot!